# How Can Convert Point Cloud to Hdf5

Tags: python, hdf5, open3d

I can convert any data to hdf5. But I have a 3D data and I am having trouble converting it to hdf5 correctly...

There are 3 different things I need to create with stl file for hdf5. Because the production must not be suitable for Modelnet40.

1.Data (X, Y, Z axis)

2.Label ?

3.Pid ?

Comment: Creating an HDF5 file is easy after you define your data schema. Conversely, it's hard until you do. :-) Tell us more details about your data. Do you want to create one data set with rows of 1.Data (X, Y, Z axis), 2.Label, and 3.Pid? Or, multiple datasets of (X, Y, Z axis) with a single Label and Pid? (saved as dataset attributes).

Comment: I want to create a data set for just one data type (tooth). Will the label value be just one? How do I calculate the pid value?

Comment: It' hard to say without seeing your data and schema. Can you create and post a small example to show what you have?

Comment: data-> 2048x2048x3 vector (x,y,z cordinates),---------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                             pid-> 2048x2048 vector (no idea, ı want to create this values) ,---------------------------------------------------- label-> 2048 values (it is constant),---------                                                                                                 I hope it will be enough...